# Kernel compare ipv6 address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In a kernel module, how do you compare an ipv6 address if you are given a `struct sockaddr_storage` and an ipv6 string literal "::1"? On linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae (x86).

```
struct sockaddr_storage ss;
... 
if(ss.ss_family == AF_INET6)
{
    // ipv6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ss;

    // compare ipv6 address
    struct in6_addr addr;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &addr); // error: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_pton’
    if( (memcmp(addr.s6_addr, sin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, sizeof(struct in6_addr)) == 0) && (htons(25) == sin6->sin6_port) )
        return -EPERM;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `inet_pton()` is not in the headers but a similar function `in6_pton()` is.

```
#include <linux/inet.h>

in6_pton("::1", -1, addr.s6_addr, -1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

The parsing function you used is userspace, that won't work in the kernel.

The actual comparison is probably better done with [`ipv6_addr_cmp()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/ipv6.h#L345) rather than a bare `memcmp()`.

Comment: Yes, but ipv6_addr_cmp() is not in the headers.

Comment: That isn't very clear; my link *is* to a header. Is that header not OK to use for drivers?

Comment: It is included inside the kernel's source code package (ipv6.h) but not in the kernel's headers package. So, you would need to build using the entire source code rather than just the headers.

Comment: It seems to be present: include/net/ipv6.h

static inline int ipv6_addr_cmp(const struct in6_addr *a1, const struct in6_addr *a2)
 {
         return memcmp(a1, a2, sizeof(struct in6_addr));
 }